# How to specify vertical and horizontal block placement independently in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the trying to use the `tikzpicture` package to place `blockB` below and to the left of `blockA`. I also want to specify both the horizontal and vertical distance between the two blocks.

```
\node [block, below left of=blockA, node distance=2.5cm] (blockB) {block B text};
```

The `node distance` parameter seems to set both the horizontal and vertical distance simultaneously. Is there any way I can decouple them?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for:`\node [block] at ([shift={(<xhift>,<yshift>)}]blockA) (blockB) {block B text};` where `<xhift>` and `<yshift>` is the x and y distance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `below left = <specify below> and <specify left> of <specify node>` syntax. This requires loading the `positioning` library.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (blockA) {block A text};
\node [draw, below left = 3cm and 1cm of blockA] (blockB) {block B text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```